# Using jQuery how can i easily show and hide a div box by moving a mouse on or off the box?

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

Here is the code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

$("#box").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });


$("#box").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).show();
});

});

</script>
```

When I move the mouse off it turns off and when I move the mouse over the "hidden"     "div" it does not appear again.  Why? and what is a simple fix?

Comment: if it's hidden, how are you going to mouseover 
it?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you need to toggle the `visibility` rather than the `display` property.

You can do this with JavaScript, but pure CSS is even better. However, you can't `:hover` over an invisible element, so you need to wrap a container around it.

```
<div id="container"><div id="box"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    background-color: blue;
    visibility:hidden;
}
#container:hover #box {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/cF4tL/

Comment: If your going to use a container as you have done then it doesn't matter if you use `display` or `visibility`.

Comment: @BlakePlumb That depends on whether you set the dimensions of the container or not.

Answer (score 0):

The 'hidden' div is being 'hidden' with the CSS display:none, you will not be able to able to trigger the mouseenter after you hide it.

Most people would shrink the div instead of completely hiding, or replace the div with some other user recognizable marker to show it again.

Having something completely invisible expect the user to mouse over something that isn't there could be considered bad design.